# Is there a way to group articles in Knowledge?

Tags: knowledge, list-view, articles, lightning-knowledge

I have recently started using Knowledge. When I launch Knowledge from apps, I can see 4 default list views - Archived Articles, Draft Articles, Published Articles and Recently Viewed Articles. These views contain all articles, but this is not feasible. Let's say I have 1000 published articles, all will appear under Published Articles view making it difficult to navigate.
Is there a way to group articles based on categories in views or any other place?